# Get response from zeromq in nodejs

Tags: node.js, zeromq

I don't understand how can I write a function that returns a zeromq response in nodejs: so far i wrote this;

```
module.exports = {

    getInfo: function(id) {

        var requester = zmq.socket('req');
        var config = 'NACK';

        requester.connect("ipc:///tmp/endpoint");

        console.log("Sending request...");
        requester.send(["GET_INFO","1234"]);

        requester.on("message", function(reply) {
            //console.log("Received reply", ": [", reply.toString(), ']');

            requester.close();
            return reply.toString();
          });
    },

}
```

If I enable the log inside the "on" callback everything is right, I receive the info I'm asking for. But if I call this function from another script the return value is "undefined". How can I "extract" those data and return them when calling the getInfo function from outside?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `return` is not related to your `getInfo` function, instead it is related to the anonymous callback function that you are defining `function(reply) {...`.

You can convert you function to return a promise, but it will require you to await it (or use `then` with a callback on the calling side):

```
module.exports = {

    getInfo: function(id) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            var requester = zmq.socket('req');
            var config = 'NACK';

            requester.connect("ipc:///tmp/endpoint");

            console.log("Sending request...");
            requester.send(["GET_INFO","1234"]);

            requester.on("message", function(reply) {
                //console.log("Received reply", ": [", reply.toString(), ']');

                requester.close();
                resolve(reply.toString());
            });
        });
    },

}
```

To learn about promises and async/await see e.g. https://javascript.info/async-await

To call the function using await could e.g. look like this:

```
var result = await getInfo(id); // Assuming the function is imported/required before
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly: changing the code this way I get a 'Promise { <pending> }' if I try to print the returned value. I tried changing everything as for the async-wait you proposed me, but unsuccessfully (again, seems like a syncronization problem, the data is not available when the function returns)

Comment: You will need to call it in an async scope as: `var result = await getInfo(id)`. Can you share the code where you are calling the `getInfo`? I might be able to give a more concrete example.